# How can I filter just a specific application android Logcat logs in IntelliJ IDE/IDEA?

Tags: android, filter, intellij-idea, logcat

I recently, change my ide from Eclipse to IntelliJ ide/idea for android development according to a lot good feedback about IntelliJ.

In general everything seems well enough, But there is one thing I can't handle it. I can filter logs by application. Eclipse users knows that when you run your program ide adds a filter for your running application. So you can read logs easily with out spamming from logs  of system/other apps .

So the questions are;
    Is there any option/method for filtering by application ?

ps: There is an [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436400/how-to-filter-only-my-application-log-in-intellijs-logcat) question on *stackoverflow* related this title, But the accepted answer can't be good enough for me or any other developer because of it's very inefficient.
You can't waste time by changing pid every restart of app.

Maybe for now this question can't be answered but,it can be stay open discussions.

***EDIT :*** ***At the latest version of intelliJ ice which will be called as Cardea they solved this problem.***

Comment: I haven't worked with IntelliJ, but that pic also allows to filter by tag. Your `Log#method()` printouts have the first argument the tag. Use that instead.

Comment: You should definitely work with tags.  They are of course independent of device/PID

Comment: tags should be specific to activities,fragments etc. not application. So , Filtering by tags is not good solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter Android logcat by application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537419/how-to-filter-android-logcat-by-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95780), most likely it's exactly what you are looking for.

Your question is probably a duplicate of this one:

- [Can IDEA's logcat filter automatically recognize running app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13539677/104891)

Comment: Thanks, for referring this ticket, I'll vote for this feature. But I hope that some developers may figure something out before this feature  will be released.

Comment: At the latest version of intelliJ idea which will be Cardea they solved this problem. For that reason I checked this answer as correct for the closing this question.